# Heroku Rails 4 assets:precompile compiles all (also unchanged) assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

On every push to Heroku, all assets are precompiled, so not only assets that have changed. Asset precompilation thus takes more than 250 seconds. I tried all suggestions I found online, but I can't seem to fix it.

I have installed the `rails_12factor` gem as suggested by Heroku. Static assets are hosted on Cloudfront. We use Bower-Rails for front-end dependencies. Unicorn is the server on Heroku.

These are some settings in the production.rb environment:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
config.assets.compile = true
config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=31536000'
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Has anyone experienced this as well? Or can anyone help me?

Comment: same. have you found a solution?

Comment: We have not found a solution. For us it is no longer an issue, since we are using Rails as API only, so we aren't using the Rails pipeline any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this before pushing to heroku?

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Then do a git commit and `git push heroku master`
I wanted to post this as a comment but didn't have the rep ><

Comment: That compiles my assets into `/public/assets` folder, but I have that in my .gitignore, because otherwise Heroku won't compile and the assets on Cloudfront are outdated.
Heroku compiles into `/tmp/build_782828...`